# Rails scope when upgrading from 3 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

While upgrading from Rails 3 to Rail 4, I got an "Invalid mix of scope block and deprecated finder options on ActiveRecord association" error. There are several posts on this issue, and some of them use a format like:

```
has_many :readable_exams,
         -> { where trashed_at: nil },
         through: :student
```

However, I'm getting the invalid error when I use this format. On the other hand, when I do:

```
has_many :readable_exams,
         -> { where(trashed_at: nil)
              .through(:student) }
```

no error gets thrown. Can anyone explain why through is throwing an error in the first case, but not the second?

**Edit:**
It turns out my error was coming from a with_options block wrapping the has_many that I ignored previously.

```
with_options source: :exams,
             primary_key: "student_id",
             group: "exams.id" do |user| # This was throwing the error
    user.has_many :readable_exams,
                  -> { where trashed_at: nil },
                  through: :student
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `through` option is not a function that is called in the scope block.  You need to say:

`has_many :exams, -> { where(trashed_at: nil) }, through: :student`

Associations now take an optional second argument, a block, which can specify certain constraints (hence scope block) for the association. You can find out which methods are valid in the guide at:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  Section 4.3.3 covers the valid methods for the `has_many` association.

One thing to keep in mind is that all methods called in the scope block are part of the `ActiveRecord` query interface and everything that comes after are options to the association.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why the second one isn't throwing an error!  I'm still confused why the first format (identical to yours) is giving me an error, though. When I delete through:, the error goes away. Any thoughts?